# unable to create a trait which defines a generic behaviour

Tags: scala

Following trait defines the common methods which a class representing a database should implement. It has a method `getOneById` which takes an `id` (say corresponding to the primary key of the table) and returns some value or `None`. The `id` could be a single value (say email id) or multiple values (say bucket id and email id), for eg, bucket =1 and email="mc@mc.com".

```
abstract trait Repository[I,M] {    
    def getOneById(id: I): Option[M]
}
```

The implementation could be (using `I` below I don't know what to define as `I`). `User` is a `case class`

```
class CassandraRepository[I ,User] (session: Session, tablename: String, partitionKeyColumns: List[String]) extends Repository [I,User] {
def getOneById(id:I): M = {

    /*eg. select * from users where bucket=1 and email='mc@mc.com';*/
    val selectStmt =
      select()
        .from(tablename)
        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(0), `some value from id should come here`)).and(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(1), `if multiple ids, some other value of id should come here`)) 
        .limit(1)


    val resultSet = session.execute(selectStmt)
    val row = resultSet.one() //get 1st value only 
    row.toUser(); //assume a function which converts row data to User case class
  }
```

What should `I` be? I am thinking that I represent the values as a `case class` but then how do I pass `case class` here as different classes could have different fields depending on the table been searched. For eg

- A `User` table could have `bucketId:Int` and `email:String` as the primary key in which case the code in the query would be       `.where(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(0), id.bucketId))).and(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(1), id.email))`
- A `Product` table could have `bucketId:Int` and `productCode:Int` as the primary key in which case the code in the query would be       `.where(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(0), id.bucketId))).and(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(1), id.productCode))`

How could I write such a generic trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, you are mixing up types and type parameters. If you want `CassandraRepository` to be generic as well, you'll have e.g.

```
class CassandraRepository[I, M](...) extends Repository[I, M] {
  // calls conditions and fromRow 
  def getOneById(id: I): Option[M] = ...

  // abstract methods which will be implemented differently depending on I and M
  def conditions(id: I): List[Clause]
  def fromRow(row: Row): M 
}

case class UserKey(bucketId: Int, email: String)

object CassandraUserRepository extends CassandraRepository[UserKey, User](...) {
  // note that here you don't use I and M, but concrete types
  def conditions(id: UserKey) = List(
    QueryBuilder.eq("bucketId", id.bucketId), 
    QueryBuilder.eq("email", id.email)
  )
  def fromRow(row: Row): User = ...
}
```

You can actually avoid the abstract `conditions` using solution in Rich's answer.

Comment: What does `conditions` do? My doubt is that if `I` is `UserKey` in your code then somewhere (either in `getOneById` or `conditions`, I would be doing `id.bucketId` and `id.email` to create the query. How is that possible because in the generic code, the compiler doesn't know that `bucketId` and `email` exist in `I`

Comment: sorry, ignore the previous comment. I was wrong. My doubt that the compiler doesn't know that `id` has `bucketId` is correct. I just tried this and got compilation error `scala>  class CassandraRepository[I, M] extends Repository[I, M] {
     |         def getOneById(id: I): Option[M] = {
     |                 println("id is "+id.bucketId)
     |                 None
     |         }
     |       }
<console>:14: error: value bucketId is not a member of type parameter I
                       println("id is "+id.bucketId)
                                           ^
`

Comment: This is possible because `conditions` are implemented in `CassandraUserRepository` where the concrete type is available. I've edited to show it.

Comment: As the last sentence says, it's actually quite possible to write `conditions` by requiring `I <: Product` (see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/Product.html) and following Rich's suggestion, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: "My doubt that the compiler doesn't know that id has bucketId is correct." It doesn't know in `CassandraRepository`, but it does in `CassandraUserRepository`.

Comment: Many thanks. I think I know where you are going with this. You mentioned earlier that I am confusing between `types` and `type parameters`. Could you please explain the difference? As far as I know, `type parameters` denoted by `I` for example means that a class or a function takes some type as an arguments but that type is not defined yet. This I cannot do `id.bucketId` for `id:I` because the compiler doesn't know that `I` has `bucketId` in it. However, we could put bounds on type parameters (eg you did `I <: Product`). `Types` is the actual type eg `UserKey`.

Comment: In the question you have `class CassandraRepository[I ,User] ...`. This means that `User` in this definition is also a type parameter, just like `I`, not the class `User`. And the last line `row.toUser(); //assume a function which converts row data to User case class` returns the wrong type.

Comment: Alexey a.k.a Genius - Your suggestion helped me move forward but am now stuck again. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908111/invalid-type-error-when-using-datastax-cassandra-driver

Comment: Ignore my message Alexey, I found the issue. Your solution was flawless!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting bogged down here. Maybe take a step back and consider whether putting lots of effort into writing one single parameterised Repository is actually better than having different Repositories for different classes.

Having said that, I think the easiest way to achieve what you want here would be to make the Id trait a `Product`, then `zip` it with the `partitionKeyColumns` and `fold` that using `QueryBuilder` to make your "where" clause.