# Invalid type error when using Datastax Cassandra Driver

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, playframework-2.6

I have a `case class` which represents partition key values.

```
case class UserKeys (bucket:Int,
                    email: String)
```

I create query `Clauses` as follows:

```
def conditions(id: UserKeys):List[Clauses] = List(
    QueryBuilder.eq("bucket", id.bucket), //TODOM - pick table description from config/env file.
    QueryBuilder.eq("email", id.email)
  )
```

And use the query as follows

```
val selectStmt =
      select()
        .from(tablename)
        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(0), whereClauseList(0))).and(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(1), whereClauseList(1))) 
        .limit(1)
```

I am getting following error.

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Clause$SimpleClause does not correspond to any CQL3 type`

**Question 1** - What am I doing wrong?
The query works on `cqlsh`

The table I am querying is

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    bucket int,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    authprovider text,
    password text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket, email), firstname, lastname)
```

**Question 2** - Is there a way to print the `List` which contains the query clauses? I tried it but I get this incomprehensible text.

`List(com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Clause$SimpleClause@2389b3ee, com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Clause$SimpleClause@927f81)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was using the query clauses incorrectly. Rather than

```
.where(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(0), whereClauseList(0))).and(QueryBuilder.eq(partitionKeyColumns(1), whereClauseList(1)))
```

I needed to do

```
.where(whereClauseList(0)).and(whereClauseList(1))
```

because the List already has `QueryBuilder.eq("bucket", id.bucket)` part